# Not able to set Xpath for my application elements in appium

Tags: java, html, xpath, appium

I am totally new in Appium. Here I am just trying to do a basic test (WebView context) for my login page app. Everything is working fine but I am not able to send values to the two input fields. Please help me out ...Thank you..

index.html:-

```
 <label class="item_input">
      <a class="item item-icon-left in-text">
        <i class="icon ion-email iconEmail"></i>
        <div class="term"> <input  id="email"type="email" placeholder="Email" class="in-text" ng-model="loginData.username" name="email" required></div></a>

      </label>
      <span style="color:white" ng-show="loginForm.username.$dirty && loginForm.username.$invalid">
        <label ng-show="loginForm.username.$error.required">Email is required</label>
      </span>
      <label class="item_input">
        <a class="item item-icon-left in-text1">
          <i class="icon ion-key iconKey"></i>
          <div class="term">  <input  id="password"type="password" placeholder="Password" class="in-text" ng-model="loginData.password"name="password" required></div></a>
        </label>
        <span style="color:white" ng-show="loginForm.password.$dirty && loginForm.password.$invalid">
          <label ng-show="loginForm.password.$error.required">Password is required.</label>

        </span>
```

my appiumTest.java:-

```
@Test
public class AppiumTest {

    private static AndroidDriver driver;

    public static void main() throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException {
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();



        // Optional

        capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "");


        // Specify the device name (any name)

        capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "Nexus");


        // Platform version

        capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "6.0.1");


        // platform name

        capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");


        // specify the application package that we copied from appium                

        capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "XXXXXXXX");


        // specify the application activity that we copied from appium                   

        capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "XXXXXXXX");

        // Start android driver I used 4727 port by default it will be 4723

            driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"),capabilities);


        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='email']")).sendKeys("hello");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='password']")).sendKeys("hello");
        // Wait for 10 second

        // Wait for 10 second

        Thread.sleep(10000);



        // close the application
         driver.quit();


    }

}
```

Error in eclipse:-

```
FAILED: main
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters. (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 78 milliseconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b', time: '2016-03-15 17:00:58'
System info: host: 'ZANDIG-PC', ip: '192.168.15.2', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_76'
*** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=//input[@id='email']}
Session ID: 6d48a8e9-9c5f-4b77-acf5-1905fe2ea853
Driver info: io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver
Capabilities [{platform=LINUX, javascriptEnabled=true, appActivity=com.orionorbit.th.MainActivity, browserName=, networkConnectionEnabled=true, desired={platformVersion=6.0.1, platformName=Android, deviceName=Nexus, appActivity=com.orionorbit.th.MainActivity, browserName=, appPackage=com.orionorbit.th}, locationContextEnabled=false, appPackage=com.orionorbit.th, platformVersion=6.0.1, databaseEnabled=false, platformName=Android, deviceName=0c35ec7f02ba5d2f, webStorageEnabled=false, warnings={}, takesScreenshot=true}]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:678)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:51)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.execute(AndroidDriver.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:363)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.findElement(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:67)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.findElement(AppiumDriver.java:1)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.findElement(AndroidDriver.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByXPath(RemoteWebDriver.java:500)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.findElementByXPath(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:145)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.findElementByXPath(AppiumDriver.java:1)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.findElementByXPath(AndroidDriver.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByXPath.findElement(By.java:361)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:355)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.findElement(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:63)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.findElement(AppiumDriver.java:1)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.findElement(AndroidDriver.java:1)
    at Appium.AppiumTest.main(AppiumTest.java:61)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:85)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:639)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:816)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1124)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:108)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:774)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:624)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:359)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:354)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:312)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:261)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1215)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1140)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1048)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:126)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:137)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:58)
```

Comment: Isn't there a space missing after the quotation marks? `id="email"type="email"` (don't know if this could impact the results)

Comment: try `driver.findElement(By.id("email")).sendKeys("hello");` also is this a webview rendered in your app?

Answer (score 0):

Based on that error, it looks like your test is throwing on

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='email']")).sendKeys("hello");
```

which seems to be line 61 for you.
This means that there's a problem finding by xpath, which may be due to the syntax.

One problem is that the 'required' attribute is left unassigned. Another problem is that the  tag is never closed.

Try this for the input tag. The difference is that the 'required' attribute is gone and the tag is closed:

```
<input id="email" type="email" placeholder="Email" class="in-text" ng-model="loginData.username" name="email"/>
```

If you want to quickly test how else you can use xpath, pay a visit to [this link](http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html).

Hope I could help :)